# Python win32com Microsoft Azure Information Protection (MAIP)

Tags: python, azure, automation, outlook, win32com

Here is some very basic code to send emails

```
# Some variables
email_reciever = "your.email@outlook.com"
email_subject = "The subject"
email_main_body = "The main body of the email"

# Open outlook and create
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("outlook.application")
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

# Contents and send
mail.To = email_reciever
mail.Subject = email_subject
mail.Body = email_main_body
mail.send()
```

The issue arrises when MIAP requires a label to classify each email with a pop up window. Is there some way of selecting one e.g. Public, as the email will not send until selected

I have never seen this issue before so any help would be much appreciated. I have noticed others have posted similar questions but none have an answer.